# mysqldump for a table dumps only one record

Tags: mysql

I am trying to take a backup of my mysql database using **mysqldump** , but when i use it on a table it dumps only one record while the table consist of more than 100 records or so, I am using the command as below

```
mysqldump -u root -p **** database1 table1 > ~/Downloads/table1.sql
```

could any one point me in the right direction?

thanks!

Comment: Your dump command is correct. This could be something related to the table itself or it could be corrupt. Try repairing the table first before doing the dump `repair table table1 quick`

Comment: try running it with out the redirection (everything from > to the end)  so you see the output on stdout, this should make the problem clearer

Comment: @Amias thanks for the hint, i can see all the data printed in the stoud

Comment: @Amias there were no error printer out, so I am gonna redirect my output into a file for now, thanks

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty repiar takes a long time, in the mean time i am going with the above solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See properly when you take backup in mysql, there is only single row created for a insert script and data in this row is comma seperated

Answer (score 0):

i was using sublime or textmate text editor in mac to view the output of mysqldump, i think they have some parsing issues for sql files. When i **cat** the files i could see the complete records. very strange !!